# If statement syntax using 'this' in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following:

```
<div class="tab-pane" id="message">
      <textarea rows="4" cols="50" id="send_message" placeholder="Enter text ...">  </textarea>
      <a href="#message" class="btn btn-large btn-info"  data-toggle="tab">OK</a>
      <a href="#message" class="btn btn-large btn-info"  data-toggle="tab">Cancel</a>
```

I want to bind the click method to the 'a' elements , and when one is clicked do separate things. I am trying to distingish between them using the button text but I'm getting a syntax error when I do:

```
$(function(){

$('#message > a').click(function(){
   if(this:contains("OK"))) {
// code to be executed if condition is true
} 
else {
// code to be executed if condition is false
}
....
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

it should be

```
if($(this).is(":contains(OK)")) {
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `filter`

```
if($(this).filter(':contains("OK")').length ) {
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/wHJ8Y/)**